# Best practice for managing multiple modals in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, modal-dialog

I have a screen and I need to show multiple modals in it. For example, if some request was failed then I want to show an error modal, if some request was successful then I want to show a success modal.

I currently do it as following which I think is bad practice:

```
...

export default function SomeSampleScreen(props) {
  const [errorModalVisible, setErrorModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
  const [successModalVisible, setSuccessModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [successMessage, setSuccessMessage] = useState('');

  function showError(message) {
    setErrorMessage(message);
    setErrorModalVisible(true);
  }

  function showSuccess(message) {
    setSuccessMessage(message);
    setSuccessModalVisible(true);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <ErrorModal
        visible={errorModalVisible}
        onClose={() => {
          setErrorModalVisible(false);
        }}>
        {errorMessage}
      </ErrorModal>
      <SuccessModal
        visible={successModalVisible}
        onClose={() => {
          setSuccessModalVisible(false);
        }}>
        {successMessage}
      </SuccessModal>
      <View>
        ...
      </View>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: If its only ui change. Whay can't you make single modal. Just pass state `success or error` based on that you can render same modal?

Comment: @ShubhamVerma What do you mean if it's only a UI change?

Comment: I mean based on state. For example this: `loading?'show loading msg':error?'show error msg':'show perfect state or do not show anything'`

Comment: @ShubhamVerma Well, I understand what you mean but it's not what I need. I have to show some modals on top of my screen component and there are multiple types of modals to show. I am looking for a way to manage those multiple modals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just condense it into one object:

```
export default function SomeSampleScreen(props) {
  const [modalState, setModalState] = useState({state: ''});

  function showError(message) {
    setModalState({state: "error", message});
  }

  function showSuccess(message) {
    setModalState({state: "success", message});
  }

  return (
    <>
      <ErrorModal
        visible={modalState.state === "error"}
        onClose={() => {
          setModalState({state: ''});
        }}>
        {modalState.message}
      </ErrorModal>
      <SuccessModal
        visible={modalState.state === "success"}
        onClose={() => {
          setModalState(false);
        }}>
        {modalState.message}
      </SuccessModal>
      <View>
        ...
      </View>
    </>
  );
}
```

UDPATE
After clarifying what the actual question is, here is a good way to do it.
Create a Context:

```
const ModalContext = React.createContext({status: "", message: ""});
```

Add the context and the modals somewhere up in your tree:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.setModal = (modalState) => {
      this.setState(state => ({...state, ...modalState}));
    };
    this.state = {
      status: "",
      message: "",
      setModal: this.setModal,
    };
  }
return <ModalContext.Provider value={this.state.modalState}>
        <RestOfApp />
        <Modals/>
      </ModalContext.Provider>
```

The Modals would be similar to what you postet:

```
export default function SomeSampleScreen(props) {
  const modalState = useContext(ModalContext);

  function showError(message) {
    modalState.setModal({state: "error", message});
  }

  function showSuccess(message) {
    modalState.setModal({state: "success", message});
  }

  return (
    <>
      <ErrorModal
        visible={modalState.state === "error"}
        onClose={() => {
          modalState.setModal({state: ''});
        }}>
        {modalState.message}
      </ErrorModal>
      <SuccessModal
        visible={modalState.state === "success"}
        onClose={() => {
          modalState.setModal(false);
        }}>
        {modalState.message}
      </SuccessModal>
      <View>
        ...
      </View>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: That would be better but I would still need to put those modal states and ErrorModal SuccessModal components to every screen that I want to show those in. I was wondering if there is a global way to show these modals without actually including them as a component in the screen.

Comment: Not sure why you down vote the answers, if the question is answered. It seems like you just have a different question to the one you asked. The best way is to add these high up into your react tree and use a global state management or context to show them. And save the states in the context. Accessing would be with useContext. I'll update my answer

Comment: Why would I downvote the answers? I didn't, it's not me. Thank you very much for your answer I am going to do your suggestion and add them high up the tree and then control them with useContext.

Comment: Since all three answers where downvoted, it looked like it. Sorry. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `conditional render` to return `different data on the same modal`.
Like this:

```js
export default function SomeSampleScreen(props) {
  const [ModalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState(false);
  const [successMessage, setSuccessMessage] = useState(false);

  function showError(message) {
    setErrorMessage(message);
    setModalVisible(true);
  }

  function showSuccess(message) {
    setSuccessMessage(message);
    setModalVisible(true);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Modal
        visible={ModalVisible}
        onClose={() => {
          setSuccessModalVisible(false);
          setSuccessMessage(false);
          setErrorMessage(false);
        }}>

        {errorMessage && (
          {errorMessage}
        )}

        { successMessage && (
          {successMessage}
        )}

      </Modal>
      <View>
        ...
      </View>
    </>
  );
}
```